# Why does my program's communication to other classes seem delayed? (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am working on a project and recently decided it needed to look prettier, so I spent a lot of time making a GUI. There is a core python module that run the algorithm and communicates back and forth with the GUI, and the intention is that the GUI should have a progress log to display to the user what is happening (sort of like how some loading screens indicates what it is currently working on.). So in my code I replaced all my `print` statements with calls to my GUI class.

For example, this:

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
do.something()
t1 = '%.2f' % (time.time() - t0)
print('Function took %d seconds' % t1)
```

I now have this:

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
do.something()
t1 = '%.2f' % (time.time() - t0)
gui.updateLog('Function took %d seconds' % t1)
```

And there are also places where I try to update the current state of a progress bar:

```
do.something()
gui.advanceProgressBar(100)
```

All of this is working well, until I get to a loop

```
loopFunction():
    i = 0
    j = 10

    while (i < j):
        do.something() #<--- function contains many calls to gui.updateLog()
        gui.advanceProgressBar(10)

    return
```

Notice that this loop is within a function (if this makes a difference to the answer). Once I try to do anything like this, nothing in the GUI updates until the loop is finished. So I don't see the progress bar go up in increments of ten percent, I just see it jump to 100. I don't see the log in the GUI updated from the calls to `updateLog()` inside of `do.something()` until the loop has finished, when I suddenly see the messages from all calls to `do.something()` appear at once. I assure that this is not a timing issue. Meaning it is not just beacsue it is all happening so fast that it seems to be at once; in my actual project the loop is much longer and takes quite a while to run, and I see no updated to the GUI appear in that time, always all at once at the end, no matter how many times the loop is run.

Inside the GUI class, the two functions in question look like this:

```
def updateLog(self, string):
    #adds lines to the activity log
    self.log.appendPlainText(string)
    return

def advanceProgressBar(self, amount):
    #changes the grpahic of the progress bar
    while(self.progress.value()<amount):
        self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 0.5)
        self.logProgress.setValue(self.progress.value())
    if(self.progress.value() == 100):
        self.enableAll()
    return
```

Why are these functions not finishing and returning until the loop is through? And if they are, why are their effects to the graphics of the GUI seemingly suspended?

I am using the Python 2 anaconda distribution, and my GUI is made with PyQt4.

Comment: The functions clearly are returning because a) the progress does (finally) update, and b) the process does complete. What is delayed is presenting those updates on the screen. My guess is that you have everything in one thread, is that right? You will probably need to run the worker functions in one thread and the gui in another thread..

Comment: Where do you call the method? Is it inside of a qt event handler?

Comment: You are in a very tight loop at `while(self.progress.value()<amount):` how is `value` updated?

Comment: @tdelaney No, I'm not sure what that means. Also, `value` is updated within the loop

Comment: @barny Yes, this is probably what I should do. The entire project really requires parallelization in its entirety in the end anyway.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks! This worked, I'll mark it as solved if you want to write an answer. Though I still probably should separate the gui handling in another thread in the future.